# How can I make a Celery Task run only after the previous task is successful

Tags: python, celery

I have two celery tasks, I want the second task to run only if the first is successful, something like this

```
@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b

@celery.task()
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b
```

First call

```
add_together.delay(2,2)
```

Second call

```
subtract.delay(4,2)
```

I want the second to run only if the first is successful

Comment: Chain them. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by chaining your tasks

```
@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b

@celery.task()
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b

celery_chain = add_together.s(2,2) | subtract.s(2)
celery_chain()
```

The returned result from add_together will be passed to the first argument of subtract in the example above. Hence, why I omitted the '4' in subtract.delay(4,2)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing tasks in chain as proposed by @pAulseperformance because the second task will be executed though the first failed. You can use callbacks to execute a task only if the previous one succeed.

```
add_together.apply_async((2, 2), link=subtract.si(4,2))
```

For more about callbacks checkout [this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#id2) or [this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#id1) for task signature